# How to run <script> when props of a component change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Is it possible to execute a `<Script/>` every time the props of a react/nextjs component change?

I am converting markdown files to html using marked and, before rendering the html, I would like to have a [copy] button on each `<pre>` block (those are the code blocks). I have a `<script/>` that iterates through the `<pre>` blocks of the DOM `document.querySelectorAll("pre")` and injects the button needed. If the html changes though at a later stage, then I have found no way to re-run the script to add the copy buttons again.

I have the impression that this is not a very react/nextjs way of doing this, so any hints would be appreciated.

The Script to add the copy buttons. I have added this as the last tag of my `<body>`:

```html
<Script id="copy-button">
          {`
          let blocks = document.querySelectorAll("pre");
          
          blocks.forEach((block) => {
            if (navigator.clipboard) {
              let button = document.createElement("img");
              button.src = "/images/ic_copy.svg"
              button.title = "Copy"
              button.id = "copy"
              button.addEventListener("click", copyCode);
              block.appendChild(button);
            }
          });
          
          async function copyCode(event) {
            const button = event.srcElement;
            const pre = button.parentElement;
            let code = pre.querySelector("code");
            let text = code.innerText;
            await navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
            button.src = "/images/ic_done.svg"

            setTimeout(()=> {
              button.src = "/images/ic_copy.svg"
            },1000)          
          }
          `}
        </Script>
```

the React component. Not much to say here. The `content` is coming from the backend. Not sure what would be the 'React' way to do this without the script.

```js
export default function Contents({ content }) {
    return (
        <div className='pl-2 pr-2 m-auto w-full lg:w-2/3 mb-40 overflow-auto break-words'>
            <div className="contents" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: You mean `<script>`, right? Note that the capitalization matters in React and `<Script>` is not the same as `<script>`.

Comment: You can react to props changes with [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: And you're right, this isn't the react way. You'll run into problems whenever data attributes change if you are manually setting data using `document.querySelectorAll`. A better option would be to wrap this logic within your React component and handle it with bound data.

Comment: You also provide very little detail, but a simple approach will be to add a `key` to your <script> that changes when the HTML changes. Use the timestamp when you last fetched, for example. If you cannot derive a key from your data that changes if and only if your HTML changes, then you should definitely reconsider your design from a React perspective.

Comment: @idmean I am using [`next/Script`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/script). Fairly new to nextjs + react so I am not entirely sure whether I should favor the one over the other. Just going with the nextjs one by default.

Comment: @AlexStyl Well-designed React applications should typically require neither except for loading specific 3rd party libraries (as shown in the Next.js examples). I'd highly recommend getting more familiar with the basics of React before using more advanced Next.js features.

Comment: Updated the question with snippets

Comment: Seeing the update, you should either learn about useEffect() and useRef() or preprocess your HTML. Needless to say, avoid `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` if you can. Maybe https://github.com/remarkjs/react-markdown works for you? This would be the best route.

Comment: @idmean thanks for sharing. Ended up using `react-markdown` after all. 

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely not do this and instead incorporate this logic into your react app, but if you must you can leverage custom window events to make logic from your html script tags happen from react.

Here is an example script:

```
<script>
  function addEvent() {
    function runLogic() {
      console.log("Stuff done from react");
    }
    window.addEventListener("runscript", runLogic);
  }
  addEvent();
</script>
```

And calling it form react like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const handleClick = () => {
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event("runscript"));
  };
  return (
    <div className="App" onClick={handleClick}>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```